# Add extra content to textarea after form submit, with jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea, form-submit

I have a textarea where I need to add some extra content to, when the form is submitted. But since the page needs some time to porcess when the form is submitted, the user can see the extra content in the textarea which is added at the submit event. I want to avoid that.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Here is my jquery:

```
$('#Formular').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var speicherAm = sessionStorage.getItem("anmerkung");
     var value = $('#comments').val();
     sessionStorage.setItem("anmerkung", value);
     returnValue = ' Gewünschte Lieferzeit: ' + speicher + '\n' + value;
     $('#comments').val(returnValue);
     $('#Formular').submit();
 })
```

Comment: Append the value to textarea in onblur function

Comment: You can't hide it in the textarea, but you could always add a hidden form field.

Comment: Add it to a `<input type="hidden">` instead and concat on the receiving part. If you have control of the receiver, that is.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't use a hidden input field, it must be in the textarea.. :(

Comment: If you're not using AJAX to submit, don't have a hidden field, or don't have control over the submit receiver, the page will return to its previous state after the submit. You won't see anything happening to the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it now with a shabby trick. Since I can't use a hidden input, I just hide the relevant textarea und replace it with a duplicate.

Here is the code:

```
$('#Formular').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $('#comments').val();
    var speicherAm = sessionStorage.getItem("anmerkung");
    sessionStorage.setItem("anmerkung", value);
    returnValue = ' Gewünschte Lieferzeit: ' + speicher + '\n' + value;
    var ersatzHeight = $('#comments').height();
    var ersatz = $('<textarea class="autosizejs form-control" maxlength="255">' + value + '</textarea>').height(ersatzHeight);
    $('#comments').val(returnValue).hide().after(ersatz);
    $('#Formular').submit();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep one more hidden field and append the textarea content and other required content and post that also while form submit.